# relative path for open method of a XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, path

In the JavaScript file containing the Ajax request what is the URL relative to? I've got the www directory containing the directories alpha and bravo. The JavaScript file in alpha and the HTML file that includes it and the PHP that processes the request in bravo.

In the JavaScript file I have `xmlhttp.open("GET", "CheckServer.php?name="+name,true);` but I don't think `CheckServer.php` is right. I've tried `../bravo/CheckServer.php` but it doesn't work.

I'm not using JQuery and I am using WAMP.

Plus, is there any trouble shooting tools I can use to see if the PHP page for processing the request is being accessed in the first place?

EDIT: I opened the console and it says the function I'm calling in the JavaScript file is not defined. This only happens when I moved the .js file to a different directory. (I modified the `<script>` tag appropiratly: `<script type="text/javascript" src="../alpha/Check.js">`.

EDIT 2: I think there is a problem with WAMP because I copy the exact same files/folders to the desktop and everything works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is relative based on the current location of the page it is called on. It has nothing to do with where the JavaScript is loaded from.

Open up the console and look at the Ajax request [console or net tab], you will see the path that it is requesting.

Answer (score 1):

It's an URL, those have nothing to do with *directories* per se. They might be mapped to directories on the server and often are but the client can never know it for sure and doesn't care. The **URL** is relative to the current **URL** (what you see in your browser address bar).

So, the question is not "where is CheckServer.php located on the server", but "how can I access it from the client".

If it's like:

```
http://example.com/alpha/index.html
http://example.com/bravo/CheckServer.php
```

fine. Use the relative URL.

But if it's like:

```
http://alpha.example.com/index.html
http://bravo.example.com/CheckServer.php
```

then it gets complicated. You will have to look into [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) because AJAX usually does not work across different domains.

Oh, and if CheckServer.php is not accessible at all... you probably can imagine the answer.